# Polish National visa (type D) refused, please help

Tags: student-visa, poland, refusal

[image]

My name is Akash. I hold a Pakistani passport and an Azerbaijani temporary resident card for one year, which will expire after 6 months. I have studied for business administration Bachelor for almost one semester and 4 months here.

I want to study in Poland for a Digital Marketing Bachelor's degree and I have given all the documents, yet they rejected my visa. Please help: I want to reapply, but I heard they will not stamp again on the 2nd attempt. But this time they will give me a proper reason. What should I do?

This time my university will provide me a letter and I have to prepare an appeal letter. I told the Poland university to call the embassy in Baku to request for my application to be reviewed. They said they would.

Comment: What supporting documents did you provide?

Comment:  Visa application form
 Azerbaijan resident card
 Picture
 Passport (Valid till 2027)
 Cover letter
 Motivation letter
 Invitation letter from university
 Admission letter from university
 Curriculum vitae
 Educational documents
 Bank statement (Own)
 Employment Letter (Sponsor)
 Bank statement of sponsor
 Salary slips of sponsor
 Accommodation proof in Poland
 Travel Insurance
 Tickets Reservation (Confirmed both sides)v

after providing these all yet I rejected

Comment: Which university have you enrolled at? It’s possible that it isn’t of sufficiently good standing with the Polish immigration authorities eg it might have a poor overseas student dropout rate. Or somehow caught up in the [‘cash for visa’ scandal](https://www.jurist.org/news/2024/01/poland-anti-corruption-agency-detains-former-minister-for-role-in-visa-payment-scandal/)

Comment: In relation to the first reason: Have you provided anything to suggest you'll leave Poland after graduation?

Comment: I enrolled At National Louis University in Nowa Sacq its private university, they just ask me three question what is your intention Of going and what do you do in Azerbaijan how long have been you here

Comment: i have attached cover letter and motivational letter but didn't write about leaving from Poland after gtraduation

Comment: National-Louis University · University of Warsaw · Poland, Warsaw. #262 QS Rankings#601-800 THE Rankings · Jagiellonian Universi

Comment: @AkashTech Why Poland, and why that particular university and degree course? Will you have completed your degree in Azerbaijan before your intended move to Poland? Or is studying in Azerbaijan just a path to try to get to Poland?